# Java : Find if values of csv string A is of the pattern of String B

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have a final string **acceptedList** which contains coma separated values.

```
final String acceptedList = "ABC, HIJ/LMN, PQR1, XYZ";
```

and another dynamic string **receivedList** which is also a csv, comes as input to my function.

```
String receivedList  = "ABC, PQR1";
```

If values in receivedList match the ones in acceptedList (in any order), it should return a success message.

Success Scenario examples:

```
receivedList  = "ABC";
receivedList  = "HIJ/LMN, ABC";
receivedList  = "XYZ, PQR1, ABC";
```

Failure Scenario examples:

```
receivedList  = "ABC, UNKNOWN";
receivedList  = "UNKNOWN";
receivedList  = "HIJ-LMN";
```

I have implemented the following code and it works fine. Is there a better way to implement this?

```
public class Driver {

    final static String acceptedList = "ABC, HIJ/LMN, PQR1, XYZ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String receivedList  = "ABC, PQR1";
        System.out.println(checkValues(receivedList));      
    }

    private static String checkValues(String receivedList) {
        List<String> acceptedListArray = Arrays.asList(acceptedList.split(", "));
        String[] receivedArray = receivedList.split(", ");
        for (String string : receivedArray) {
            if (!acceptedListArray.contains(string)) {
                return "Error!";
            }
        }
        return "Success!";
    }
}
```

Output

```
Success!
```

Comment: If you can use library function provided by list then you don't need the loop.

Answer (score 3):

### [`Set#containsAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#containsAll(java.util.Collection))

I suggest you store the values in sets to avoid duplicate values being processed again and then use `Set#containsAll` to check if all the values in `receivedList` are present in `acceptedList`.

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class Driver {

    final static String acceptedList = "ABC, HIJ/LMN, PQR1, XYZ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String receivedList = "ABC, PQR1";
        System.out.println(checkValues(receivedList));

        receivedList = "ABC, UNKNOWN";
        System.out.println(checkValues(receivedList));
    }

    private static String checkValues(String receivedList) {
        Set<String> acceptedListSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(acceptedList.split(", ")));
        Set<String> receeivedListSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(receivedList.split(", ")));

        return acceptedListSet.containsAll(receeivedListSet) ? "Success!" : "Failure!";
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Success!
Failure!
```

Answer (score 2):

You may convert both CSV inputs to arrays using `String#split`.  Then, convert them to lists and use `List#containsAll` to do the assertion:

```java
public class Driver {
    final static String acceptedCSV = "ABC, HIJ/LMN, PQR1, XYZ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String receivedCSV  = "ABC, PQR1";
        System.out.println(receivedCSV + " => " + checkValues(receivedCSV));      
        receivedCSV  = "ABC, DEF";
        System.out.println(receivedCSV + "  => " + checkValues(receivedCSV));      
    }

    private static String checkValues(String receivedCSV) {
        List<String> acceptedList = Arrays.asList(acceptedCSV.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
        List<String> receivedList = Arrays.asList(receivedCSV.split("\\s*,\\s*"));

        return acceptedList.containsAll(receivedList) ? "Success!" : "Error!";
    }
}
```

This prints:

```
ABC, PQR1 => Success!
ABC, DEF  => Error!
```